# How to publish a custom Facebook Open Graph story using its ID

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a Javascript based HTML Facebook game, and I'm currently creating a share button to allow players to share their score and rank when they finish a level.

Since different players will have different ranks and scores I'm POSTing the player's score to their own individual story like this:

```
function shareResult(){

// Here I'm creating a custom story by inserting the player's rank and score using ``getElementById`` to get the rank and score. This player's unique story is saved in Facebook in ``me/objects/game.achievement`` 

FB.api(

    "/me/objects/game.achievement",
    "POST",

    {        "object": "{\"fb:app_id\":\"607362846726234\",\"og:type\":\"game.achievement\",\"og:url\":\"http://apps.facebook.com/myurlwithmetatags\",\"og:title\":\"I just ranked "+document.getElementById('myrank').innerHTML+" in the game with a score of "+document.getElementById('myscore').innerHTML+"\",\"og:image\":\"https:\\\/\\\/s-static.ak.fbcdn.net\\\/images\\\/devsite\\\/attachment_blank.png\",\"game:points\":\"250\"}"
    },

    function (response) {

      if (response && !response.error) {

        console.log(response);

// Here I'm attemptng to publish the custom story to the player's timeline by telling it to publish the story that has the ID of the newly created story, this ID is returned as ``(response)``, so I store it as the variable ``theachievement``, and then try to publish that:

    var theachievement = response;

    FB.api( 

    "/me/objects/game.achievement",
    "POST",

    {
        "id": theachievement
    },

    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
         console.log("Story should now be published on player's timeline");
      }
    }
);
```

This code is successfully creating the story and saving it in `me/objects/game.achievement` (The rank and score appears correctly when I test it in Facebook's Graph API. But there's something wrong with the code that's supposed to publish the story to the user's timeline.

I have the correct permissions (publish permissions), so I think there must be an error in the second half of my code somewhere.

Any help with this would be really appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you see it in the activity log?

Comment: Hi @WizKid the activity log is showing "Emily R. posted an achievement via MyTestingGameTwo." whenever I hit the share button, and I can see the new data appearing in the Graph API when I query that, but the second part of my code, where I'm trying to grab that data and "share" it isn't working.

Comment: No I mean https://www.facebook.com/me/allactivity

Comment: Hi again, yep that's where the "Emily R. posted an achievement via MyTestingGameTwo." is appearing. A new one appears in the list whenever I press the share button.

Comment: Then everything is working. Not everything is displayed on timeline

Comment: I'm a little confused, because earlier I wrote some code for a normal Facebook Open Graph share (the type where you specify a url and Facebook posts the story to your timeline using the data at that url), that showed up on my timeline perfectly, and in the activity log it says "Emily R. shared a link." But I can't seem to get a custom story to share in the same way, it's not saying "shared" in the activity log, it looks as though only the first half of my code is working (storing the story inside Facebook), but the second half isn't (sharing the story on my timeline for others to see).

Comment: You are posting to the exact same endpoint twice – with different data each time. How is that supposed to make sense? / Have you logged the result object to console, and inspected what it contains?

Comment: Hi @CBroe thanks for your comment, I'm planning to have the share button create the achievement the first time a player completes the game, from then on I want to update that existing achievement whenever the share button is pressed (I haven't written that code yet), instead of creating multiple achievements (which is what it's currently doing, it's resulting in multiple achievements with multiple unique IDs). The console.log of the result gives me the ID for that particular achievement entry, and when I inspect that in the Graph API Explorer it gives me detailed data of the achievement.

Comment: I'm wondering is it possible to use the ID returned in the response/result of the creation of the story, as a reference to then publish that story to player's timeline?

Comment: You _have_ different achievements, so don’t try and cram them all into one achievement object – creating a _new_ one when the player achieves something new in your app, would be the correct way of doing this IMHO.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I don't think I explained it well, I don't know if achievement is the correct object to use. I'm trying to share the player's new rank and score inside an Open Graph story, in a way the "achievement" would be the same every time (completing the game), only the rank and score in the description would be different. I had another question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36838906/how-to-include-variables-in-a-facebook-open-graph-story but I'm not sure my current attempt is the correct method to use.

Comment: Hi @CBroe I think I've worked out how to store player-unique variables (like rank & score) into a Facebook Story correctly using POST, but do you have any advice on how to publish the Open Graph story to your feed using only its ID as a reference? It seems that you have to define a href in order to use ``share``, is there some way to use the ID as the href, or to somehow point the href to the data stored at that ID in the Graph API? You seem very knowledgeable about developing on Facebook and I'd really appreciate any further help, thanks again for your time.

Comment: You can pass either a URL or an object id when publishing your OG story. You just need to use the object name as the parameter name.

Comment: Although for achievements, it specifically says you need to use a URL, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/app/achievements#publish – you can try with an id and see if that works, even though not documented … if not, you’ll have to use a URL.